# Prevent Screen Capture in Android One Devices

Tags: java, android, kotlin, screenshot

I want to prevent screenshot capture in android phones. I added the line

`requireActivity().window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)`

This is working fine in normal devices. But when I try on android one devices, ( https://www.android.com/intl/en_in/one/ ), it is still capturing screenshots.

I tried other apps like AmazonPrime, Hotstar, and GooglePay on android one devices... In which though they are capturing the screenshots, the content is entirely black. How to achieve that or prevent a screenshot in android one devices.

Answer (score 0):

We can listen to `FileObserver` to detect when screenshot captured. Then delete the captured screenshot file from the storage.

Here is the sample code for the `MediaListenerService`

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.FileObserver;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile;

import java.io.File;

public class MediaListenerService extends Service {

    public static FileObserver observer;
    private Context context;

    public MediaListenerService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;
        startWatching();
    }

    private void startWatching() {
        //The desired path to watch or monitor
        String pathToWatch = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                + File.separator + "Screenshots" + File.separator;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service is Started and trying to watch " + pathToWatch, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        observer = new FileObserver(pathToWatch, FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS) { // set up a file observer to watch this directory
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int event, final String file) {
                if (event == FileObserver.CREATE || event == FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE || event == FileObserver.MODIFY || event == FileObserver.MOVED_TO && !file.equals(".probe")) { // check that it's not equal to .probe because thats created every time camera is launched
                    String filePath = pathToWatch + file;
                    Log.d("MediaListenerService", "File created [" + filePath + "]");
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
//                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), file + " was saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        File screenShotFile = new File(pathToWatch, file);
                        if (screenShotFile.exists()) {
                            try {
                                boolean isDeleted = screenShotFile.delete();
                                if (isDeleted) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), file + " was deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Log.d("MediaListenerService", "File deleted [" + filePath + "]");
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, 200L);
                }
            }
        };
        observer.startWatching();
    }
}
```

Add file permission in `Manifest`

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Register your service in `Manifest` under application tag:

```
<service
  android:name=".MediaListenerService"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="false" />
```

And check file storage permission and start service in MainActivity under `onCreate`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startService(Intent(baseContext, MediaListenerService::class.java))
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                123
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree this works for deleting the files….But I want to prevent it beforehand rather than storing and deleting later…Also, this would require me to get access to storage permission too…which I think is not a better idea just for preventing screenshots. Also, if I do not stop the service properly, there might be a chance for the user's out of the app screenshots to get deleted too...

Comment: Yup, we need to stop the service once the app is closed/paused.